# Vala/Genie builds for Win/Mac?

Tags: vala, genie

Is the Vala/Genie compiler available on the Windows and Mac OS X platforms? I know that it is possible to use GLib and GTK on Windows and Mac OS X, but there are no official downloads of Vala for either platform.

Comment: Your question came across as accusing the Vala developers of acting in bad faith. While the original question about platforms is a valid thing to ask, I've edited it to be more neutral. Please take a more friendly tone in future.

Answer (score 1):

Vala 0.28 is currently [available](https://github.com/jralls/gtk-osx-build/blob/master/modulesets-stable/gtk-osx-random.modules#L82) on Mac OS X in just the same way as the rest of the GLib/GTK platform is. [Here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/OSX/Building) are the official instructions for setting up a GLib/GTK development environment on Mac OS X. To build the Vala/Genie compiler, run `jhbuild build vala` after completing those instructions.

I don't know the answer for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "official" builds of Vala as such. Vala is officially released as source code only. The source is then built by various distributors who package and distribute the builds.

On Linux this is done by distributions like Fedora and Ubuntu. On Mac OS X probably the most relevant is [Brew](http://brew.sh/) and on Windows [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/). For more details on all of these ways see the [Installing Vala](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ValaPlatforms) section of the Vala wiki.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of getting Vala compiler to work on Windows. The easiest solution would be installing [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io/) which always provides fresh version of vala as one of it's packages.